# Java inheritance: What is the difference between method overriding and method hiding?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass *overrides* the superclass's method.

While in case of static methods

> If a subclass defines a static method with the same signature as a static method in the superclass, then the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass.

So, I have tested the code example shown there with addition of more use cases:
The super class `Animal`:

```java
public class Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The static method in Animal");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Animal");
    }
}
```

The subclass `Cat`:

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The static method in Cat");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Cat");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Animal.testClassMethod();
        Cat.testClassMethod();
        animal.testInstanceMethod();
        myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

The output here is:

> The static method in Animal
> The static method in Cat
> The instance method in Animal
> The instance method in Cat

So, I still see no actual difference between *overriding* the superclass *instance* method with subclass instance method with the same signature and overriding (*hiding*) the superclass *static* (class) method with subclass static method with the same signature.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You are seeing a different as you are calling `myAnimal.testInstanceMethod` which is actually calling the method on `Cat` whilst the static method (if you would do `myAnimal.testClassMethod` would be the one from Animal.

Comment: Try `animal = cat; animal. ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding it means that you can't call `super.method()` in the sub class's implementation.

So for example

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        super.testClassMethod(); //this is not possible
        System.out.println("The static method in Cat");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        super.testInstanceMethod(); //this is fine
        System.out.println("The instance method in Cat");
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, thank you. But I still not sure. When I'm trying to put `super.testClassMethod()` in subclass `Cat` method `testClassMethod()` I get `"Cat.super" cannot be referenced from a static content` notification. But I still can put `super.testClassMethod()` reference inside the `Cat` `testInstanceMethod` and it successfully prints `The static method in Animal` from there!

Comment: So currently I see the issue is not between `hiding` vs `overriding`. You simply `cannot be referenced from a static content` to any upper class object etc.

Comment: The "cannot be referenced from a static context" happens because you try to access a non-static atribute or method from a static method.

Answer (score 2):

You can call super() in an object method (not static), but you can not call super in a static method because there is no "super" object to call to.